# Ошибка jQueryxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx was not called

Tags: php, jquery, json

Получаю эту ошибку  jQueryxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx was not called.

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
            type : "GET",
            url : 'https://xxx/api/postcode_v_1.php?id='+postcode+'',           
            dataType : "jsonp",
```

файл postcode_v_1.php возвращает:

```
{"0":"58859","id":"58859","1":"1822KC","code":"1822KC","2":"1822 KC","code_new":"1822 KC","3":"Leopoldstraat","straat":"Leopoldstraat","4":"1 t/m 71","nummers":"1 t/m 71","5":"Alkmaar","plaats":"Alkmaar","6":"Alkmaar","gemente":"Alkmaar","7":"Noord-Holland","region":"Noord-Holland"}
```

Содержит:
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo stripslashes(json_encode($row_post));

Comment: А зачем вам `callback=?` в урле? Почему значение = `?`?

Comment: убрал callback=? из урла, в примере было.

Comment: Если dataType : "jsonp" изменить  на json то все работает на одном домене, но если обращаться с другого к  
jQuery.ajax({ 
            type : "GET",
            url : 'https://xxx/api/postcode_v_1.php?id='+postcode+'',           
            dataType : "json",
то уже  не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять dataType : "json",

Если вы все-таки хотите посылать кросс-доменный запрос, вам нужно добавить в заголовок ответа Access-Control-Allow-Origin "anotherdomain.com" или "*", но это не очень хороший выбор...

Comment: Как обезопасить используя Access-Control-Allow-Origin *?

Comment: Не используйте *, указывайте конкретный домен.
А еще лучше сделайте авторизацию, например по токену, и посылайте запрос с помощью curl.